# How to compare the performance between two codes by static analyzing?

Tags: performance, llvm, compiler-optimization

I'm studying llvm recently.

I have a C code name `cal.c`. Now, I apply two different optimization passes on this code and generate two different IR codes - `cal1.ll` and `cal2.ll`.

How could I compare the performance between them?

I tried compare instruction counts and instruction cost but those of them are not good features. **I think there are no relations between instruction counts and performance, instruction costs and performance.**

So, how could I compare the performance between two IR?

I don't need to know the run time. **I just want to know which is the faster.**

Comment: You are right, there's hardly any correlation between those sizes. As for the rest... it's dificult. Really, really difficult, and growing more difficult by the year as CPUs grow more complex. Sometimes you can simplify the problem by exploiting special traits of your code. e.g. if one of the two is always is the same as the other plus a memory barrier. Good luck.

Comment: You cannot tell which IR is faster without generating low-level assembly on a given target architecture and the result will be very dependent of the target processor. Indeed, for example some instruction are slow on AMD processor while the same are fast on Intel while both are x86-64 architecture. Even the order of the instruction and they address matters a lot in some cases. There are tools to estimate the speed of the generated assembly code however they are not very good yet. Moreover they cannot take into account runtime-dependent event (eg. cache misses and branch misses).

Comment: I know it is hard to measure the run time by static. But I just want to compare which is faster between two IR.
The way I calculate the total costs is using the module from llvm name - cost model.cpp. In my point, this module may measure the cost according to the target hardware.

Comment: If seeing which one is faster doesn't depend on estimating speed, then it must depend on something else. The only thing I can think of is comparative analysis to determine that one does all that the other does, and then something more, which makes it slower. Your question doesn't go into what properties your code has that might enable this sort of comparative analysis, so in a way, you're asking a question and hiding the information that could be used to answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hard problem, often much harder than just running you code on the actual hardware and measure which is faster. It more or less boils down to simulate the hardware using "pen and paper". You will need a detailed model of the target system including things like pipeline and cache behavior and then use this model to calculate the cost of each executed instruction.

Answer (score 0):

[llvm-mca](https://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-mca.html) tries to statically estimate performance of assembly code by reusing LLVM compiler's CPU pipeline model:

```
$ llvm-mca -mcpu=skylake foo.s
Iterations:        300
Instructions:      900
Total Cycles:      610
Total uOps:        900
```

As mentioned by others, the estimates would be imprecise (often very imprecise) due to lack of cache and branch predictor models, imprecision of CPU pipeline model, etc.